# bash get back interpreted escape string

Tags: bash, escaping, command-substitution

Consider the following bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tstring="Hi\tThere"
istring=$(echo -e $tstring)
echo $istring   # Prints: Hi There
rstring=$(printf '%q' "$istring") # This is not doing what I intended
echo $rstring  # Prints: $'Hi\tThere'
```

I want rstring to be the same as tstring so that I can test for equality. So basically how do I undo the operation that created istring and get back tstring?

Comment: You can't really do that reliably, because once it's converted to the TAB character there's no way to know whether the original escape sequence was `\t` or `\011` or `\x09` or `\u0009`...

Comment: ok that makes sense, in that case I will just have to strip out all the spaces so that I can compare them. thanks.

Comment: `printf "%q" "$string"` converts the `$string` in  a format that can be
reused as shell input. The form looks like `$'string'` which may include backslash
escape sequences. You can mostly retrieve the original string `tstring` 
by removing leading `$'` and trailing `'`. Please try something like:
`rstring=${rstring:2:${#rstring}-3}`.

Comment: Tangentially you actually want `printf -v rstring '%q' "$istring"`